# Multiple login windows/keeps re-prompting for username/password on acquireToken()

Tags: cordova-plugins, adal

Every time I make a call to acquireToken, it keeps launching the AAD login window and prompts me for a username/password, even though I've already authenticated successfully and consumed an access token to make API calls.

Here is my code

```
Step 1. Call the loadData function from controller
    loadData = (): Rx.IPromise<Array<UserResult>> => {
        var url = this.xxxApiUrl;
        return Http.get<Array<UserResult>>(this._$http, url);
    };

Step -2
export function get<TResult>(http: ng.IHttpService, url: string, 
ignoreLoadingBar: boolean = false, retryCount = 0): Rx.IPromise<TResult> {
    var req: any = {};
    if (ignoreLoadingBar) {
        req.ignoreLoadingBar = ignoreLoadingBar;
    }
    let resObservable = Rx.Observable.create(subscriber => {
        acquireToken(url, (message, token) => {
            req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
            http.get(url, req)
                .then(res => {
                    subscriber.onNext(res.data);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }, (err) => { alert(JSON.stringify(err)); });
        });
    });
    return resObservable.toPromise();
}

function acquireToken(apiUrl: string, callback) {
    let innerCallback = (res) => callback('', res.accessToken);
    let xConfig= JSON.parse(<any>sessionStorage.getItem('xConfig'));
    window.AuthenticationContext = new 
   window.Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext
 (xConfig.common.azure.authorityTenant);
    window.AuthenticationContext.tokenCache.readItems().then(items => {
        if (items.length > 0) {
            let authority = items[0].authority;
            window.AuthenticationContext = new 
 window.Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
        }
        let resourceUri = getResourceUri(xConfig, apiUrl);
        window.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUri, 
  xConfig.common.azure.clientId, xConfig.common.azure.redirectUri)
            .then(innerCallback, (err) => {
                window.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, 
  xConfig.common.azure.clientId, xConfig.common.azure.redirectUri)
                    .then(innerCallback);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like that you are using `acquireTokenSilentAsync` using the *common* endpoint, this is not supported. Please make sure to use your tenant Id or name (like tenant.onmicrosoft.com) instead of *common* when using `acquireTokenSilentAsync`

For more information about the *common* endpoint please see [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant)